# -bash: installation: No such file or directory in Mac Terminal

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal

When I load my Terminal I get:

```
Last login: Tue Jun  2 22:26:10 on ttys001
-bash: installation: No such file or directory
User:~ user$
```

What do the following mean:

- `ttys001`
- `-bash: installation: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The term TTY is short for "teletype" (from those [old teletype terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)). It's simply the device used to connect the standard file handles (standard out, standard in and standard error) to the terminal. The numbers are just a sequence number, as there are many such devices.

That line simply says that last time you logged in, it was on the terminal device `ttys001`.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. Do you know what "-bash: installation: No such file or directory " means ?

Comment: @MrT No, that's probably something in the Bash initialization scripts (`.bash_profile` (or alternatively `.profile`) or `.bashrc`).